# Sort/filter does not work on the same column

Tags: react-data-grid

When i try to apply sort/filter in same column it is not rendering the sort properties. If i remove my filterRenderer then sort is working properly. I am using react-data-grid by adzalle.

Here is piece of code:-

```
{
                key: 'description',
                name: 'Description',
                //width: 80,
                renderCell: ({ row }) => {
                    return <div title={row.description}>{row.description}</div>
                },
                headerCellClass: filterColumnClassName,
                renderHeaderCell: (p) => (
                    <FilterRenderer {...p}>
                        {({ filters, ...rest }) => (
                            <FilterByInput
                                {...rest}
                                {...filters}
                                changeHandler={handleChangeInput}
                                inputKey={'description'}
                            />
                        )}
                    </FilterRenderer>
                ),
                resizable: true,
                sortable: true
            },
```

In data grid i am passing props as :-

onSortColumnsChange={setSortColumns}
sortColumns={sortColumns}

React version: 18.0
React data grid version: "^7.0.0-beta.34"

I want to have proper sort/filter functionality giving expected results.